# Intel laptop webcam not recognized, only works in Windows

Tags: drivers, webcam, 23.04, cheese

I have an Intel N3450 mini laptop.

The webcam was working under Windows 10 as "Intel AVStream" camera, after installing ubuntu 23.04 the webcam is not recognized. I also tried live iso of Fedora and Manjaro but no luck. Apps like Skype/Discord/Cheese cannot find any webcam device.

This is the list of USB hardware of my laptop:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c21 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And list of my PCI-E devices:

```
$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Host Bridge [8086:5af0] (rev 0b)
00:00.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5a8c] (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 500 [8086:5a85] (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Multimedia controller [0480]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Imaging Unit [8086:5a88] (rev 0b)
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster [8086:5a98] (rev 0b)
00:0f.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Trusted Execution Engine [8086:5a9a] (rev 0b)
00:12.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SATA AHCI Controller [8086:5ae3] (rev 0b)
00:14.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series PCI Express Port B #2 [8086:5ad7] (rev fb)
00:15.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series USB xHCI [8086:5aa8] (rev 0b)
00:16.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #1 [8086:5aac] (rev 0b)
00:16.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #2 [8086:5aae] (rev 0b)
00:16.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #3 [8086:5ab0] (rev 0b)
00:16.3 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #4 [8086:5ab2] (rev 0b)
00:17.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #5 [8086:5ab4] (rev 0b)
00:17.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #6 [8086:5ab6] (rev 0b)
00:17.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #7 [8086:5ab8] (rev 0b)
00:17.3 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series I2C Controller #8 [8086:5aba] (rev 0b)
00:18.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #1 [8086:5abc] (rev 0b)
00:18.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #2 [8086:5abe] (rev 0b)
00:18.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #3 [8086:5ac0] (rev 0b)
00:18.3 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series HSUART Controller #4 [8086:5aee] (rev 0b)
00:19.0 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #1 [8086:5ac2] (rev 0b)
00:19.1 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #2 [8086:5ac4] (rev 0b)
00:19.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SPI Controller #3 [8086:5ac6] (rev 0b)
00:1b.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDXC/MMC Host Controller [8086:5aca] (rev 0b)
00:1c.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series eMMC Controller [8086:5acc] (rev 0b)
00:1e.0 SD Host controller [0805]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SDIO Controller [8086:5ad0] (rev 0b)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Low Pin Count Interface [8086:5ae8] (rev 0b)
00:1f.1 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series SMBus Controller [8086:5ad4] (rev 0b)
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3165 [8086:3165] (rev 81)
```

I guess this multimedia controller might be the integrated webcam device?
Because it shows [disabled] in `lspci -v` output:

```
00:03.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Imaging Unit (rev 0b)
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 21
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16M]
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 3
```

But I'm lost now. How could I start to solve the non-functional webcam? Please advise.

EDIT:

Here are the video device listed:

```
$ sudo lshw -class video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 500
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 0b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:124 memory:91000000-91ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be supported by Linux as of now:
https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=pci:8086-5a88

Comment: Thanks. That was unfortunate.